# Cannot print list of string in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm having a trouble printing list of strings in django template: Here is template:

```
{% for column in columns %}
   alert({{column}});
{% endfor %}
```

size of columns is 3 and its ok. If i put `alert("aaa");` then alert is shows 3 times. And if i write `alert({{column|length}});` alert show 3. Why i cannot display column value like in code above?

I'm tried and `alert(column);` and `alert({{column|safe}});` and nothing...

Answer (score 2):

Just put it into quotes:

```
{% for column in columns %}
   alert("{{column}}");
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Oh my god O.o :) Thanks!